# Where have I made a mistake in Angular Routing?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am trying to put some of my routings outside of the main Routing but I've got an error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module ‘app/user/user.module’

I've got two routing files and two module files in my application: MainRouting and UserRouding

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: 'app/user/user.module#UserModule' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```
// Routing Module for Child-Components - User | Requests

import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// Child Components
import { CreateComponent } from './create/create.component';
import { EditComponent } from './edit/edit.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'create', component: CreateComponent },
  { path: '', component: ListComponent },
  { path: 'edit/:id', component: EditComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class UserRoutingModule {}
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { UserRoutingModule } from './user-routing.module';

import { EditComponent } from './edit/edit.component';
import { CreateComponent } from './create/create.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule, UserRoutingModule ],
  declarations: [ EditComponent, CreateComponent, ListComponent ]
})

export class UserModule {}
```

I want to separate my routings and modules as explicitly as it's possible

Comment: Sorry, it says the following: ERROR: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot fins module ‘app/user/user.module’

Comment: @R.Richards , I’ve checked the code three times but cannot find why this error occurred. That’s the first time I am trying to divide my routing

Comment: @R.Richards I tried to play around with the module path but it didn’t work as well. From where should the path start to my ChildRoute, from the root or any other place? And should there be hashtag separating path with the module name?

Comment: Have you tried using relative path for your lazy loaded module?

Comment: @yurzui , my app-routing.module.ts is on the same level with user folder which includes my file user.module.ts. In my app-routing.module I used the path like: ‘user/user.module#UserModule’ did you mean that?

Comment: Something like `'./user/user.module#UserModule'`

Comment: @yurzui , Thank you! It helped